# How can I skip the Sudden Death (water rising) cutscene in Worms Forts: Under Siege?

Tags: worms-forts-under-siege

The cutscene when the "Mighty Being" (if I remember right) comes out and raises the water level is time-wasting!

Is there anyway to skip the water rising cutscene, without disabling the water rising effect?